# See today's traffic in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to see the traffic on a website from today till now? 
I only see stats from the last day and I'd like to see stats from this day to the hour so is that even possible? I couldn't find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is very simple. login to yours site and check the top right corner in the oview of your site and change the date to one day.

Answer (score 14):

So, in an effort to keep everything on SO and up to date, here is the process:

1. Login 
   [image: Login image]
2. Choose the relevant site
   [image: Look, it's my site!]
3. Click on the date selector
   [image: Selector]

   It might look like this:
   [image]
4. Select today’s date (and only today’s date). 
   [image: Choose today]
5. Click "Apply"
6. Profit!!!

Comment: [And here's a link which doesn't 404!](http://allen-poole.com/wordpress/2015/01/how-to-get-todays-results-in-ga/#more-1711), though it is self-serving.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible, you have just Real Time menu but it's not the answer of your question

Comment: Selecting today's date range shows relevant details

Answer (score 1):

If you set the date from today to today in the user interface, that will give you data for today to the point the last data was collected.  It might not be completely in real time, but it's good enough to give you an idea.